# file system issue when i use vagrant+docker on windows

Tags: windows, vagrant, docker, supervisord, vagrantfile

this is my vagrant file

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "app" do |app|
    app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir = "."
      d.cmd = ["/sbin/my_init", "--enable-insecure-key"]
    end
  end
  config.ssh.username = "root"
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "insecure_key"
end
```

This is my docker file

```ruby
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.15
MAINTAINER neetu

ENV HOME /root
RUN mkdir /buzzbuild
ADD . /buzzbuild
RUN cd /buzzbuild/ && chmod 777 install.sh && sh install.sh
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
EXPOSE 80 443 5000 15672
```

so as you can see ..
1) i am adding my buidl directory(.) to  /buzzbuild
2) and am running  a install script there (after i CD into that dir)

and i get

root@8bde177d1bc2:/buzzbuild# ./test2.sh
-bash: ./install.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

the contents of the install script are :-

```ruby
#!/bin/sh
#apt-get update
apt-get update
apt-get install -y -q git
```

If i create new file (test.sh) adn change permissions on it and add the same content it works.

but the install.sh script does not work.

I suspect its a problem of files getting added from windows to ubuntu(container)

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

### what's wrong

The error message `root@8bde177d1bc2:/buzzbuild# ./test2.sh -bash: ./install.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` gives you a hint that your *install.sh* file has Windows style end of lines.

Windows end of lines are made of two characters: `\r\n` while Linux end of lines are just `\n`. `^M` represents the `\r` character in the error message.

### what to do

Either make sure all your scripts are using Linux style end of line before building your image or in your Dockerfile add a RUN statement that fixes end of lines:

```
ADD . /buzzbuild
RUN cd /buzzbuild/ \
    && sed -i 's/\r//' install.sh \
    && chmod 777 install.sh \
    && sh install.sh
```

Comment: your diagnosis is correct. The problem is line endings.

Comment: But the solution for some reason is not working .. i tried 2 things to solve that issue .. but both of them result in hang ups on "building container from Dockerfile"

Comment: FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.15
  MAINTAINER neetu

  ENV HOME /root
  RUN mkdir /buzzbuild
  RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q  dos2unix
  ADD . /buzzbuild
  #RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q  dos2unix
  #RUN cd /buzzbuild/ && dos2unix *.sh && chmod 755 install.sh && sh    install.sh
  RUN cd /buzzbuild/ \
    && sed -i 's/\r$//' install.sh \
    && chmod 777 install.sh \
    && sh install.sh
  CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
  EXPOSE 80 443 5000 15672

Comment: I found a mistake in the code I suggested. Replace `sed -i 's/\r$//' install.sh` with `sed -i 's/\r//' install.sh` and it should be fine. the _dos2unix_ way should work as well but requires to install dos2unix beforehand

Comment: Actually for some reason i am not able to style my comment properly but if you noticce..I did install dos2unix in the container before running it.                                                                              `RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q  dos2unix
RUN cd /buzzbuild/ && dos2unix *.sh && chmod 755 install.sh && sh install.sh`

Comment: BTW I tried it with corrected script as well .. still stuck and "buidling container" ..also even if the sed is incorrect .. it should return right ? the script can fail but what i dont understand is getting stuck

Comment: I would advise to ensure first that your Dockerfile is OK by building it using the docker commands and without using the vagrant provider. Once you are confident Docker isn't the issue you can integrate this work with vagrant